# Android studio taking a picture and saving

Tags: android

I try take a picture and then save it into application, so can I can display it there and store in some ListViews.

```
package com.example.courses

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ListFragment.Updater {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "smile ... taking picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 690)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "sorry .. no picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

This code works, as the picture is indeed asked to be created. However, I'm not sure, where can I access this picture once is created, or which variable stores it after and how can I actually access this variable in order to show the image. Can you give me any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you are capturing Images or accessing any other files form File Manager all result can be captured in onActivityResult() method as follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ListFragment.Updater {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "smile ... taking picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 690)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "sorry .. no picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
when(requestCode) {
    690 -> {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap)
        }
    }
    else -> {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unrecognized request code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    }
   }
 }
}
```